# Getting SQL script from Hibernate update

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, tomcat

I'm looking for way to get the SQL update script when Hibernate automatically updates tables.

I'm using `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update` in development environment only, and I need SQL script that updates tables for production.

I want these SQL scripts in txt format for revision and potential edit.

How can this be done?
Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some suggestions and general discussion [here](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t44119.html).

In a nutshell, you can turn on logging (to standard output):

```
hibernate.show_sql=true
```

Alternatively, if you use log4j, you can add this to your log4j.properties file:

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
```

Both of these approaches are going to output Hibernate's prepared statements with parameters (so the parameter values themselves are not inline). To get around this, you could use an interceptor like [P6Spy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/p6spy/). Details on that can be found [here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-display-hibernate-sql-parameter-values-solution/).

Answer (score 0):

`org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration` class has method:

```
public java.lang.String[] generateSchemaUpdateScript( Dialect, DatabaseMetadata)
```

what generates the reqiured update script.

I've just implemented this in grails:

```
configuration = new DefaultGrailsDomainConfiguration(
                    grailsApplication: grailsApplication,
                    properties: props) 
//this extends hibernate config

Connection c = SessionFactoryUtils.getDataSource(sessionFactory).getConnection(props.'hibernate.connection.username', props.'hibernate.connection.password')
<br/>md = new DatabaseMetadata(c, DialectFactory.buildDialect(props.'hibernate.dialect'))

configuration.generateSchemaUpdateScript(DialectFactory.buildDialect(props.'hibernate.dialect'), md)
)
check SchemaExport script in grails, for further information, it uses hibernate to generate schema.
```

(I had to implent is as a service because we have external domain model)