# How to make Hibernate to create database SQL script for initialization and update

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, initialization

Hibernate is able to create database structure. Below is example how configuration looks using [JPA2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API#JPA_2.0) with `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>`
( Use Hibernate Entity Manager in the case)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
            <!-- value="create" to build a new database on each run; value="update" to modify an existing database; value="create-drop" means the same as "create" but also drops tables when Hibernate closes; value="validate" makes no changes to the database -->
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>
            <!-- Uncomment the following two properties for JBoss only -->
            <!-- property name="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl" value="false" /-->
            <!-- property name="hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners" value="false" /-->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**How to make Hibernate to create database SQL script for initialization and update?** (that could be run manually or via batch execution) and what tools to use for that.

Yes, there are SQL statements in log (Q [Getting SQL script from Hibernate update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093201/getting-sql-script-from-hibernate-update) ), but that is not clean solution.

The goal is to prepare solution for automated database upgrade with every version release.

Comment: I wonder whether http://stackoverflow.com/questions/835961/how-to-creata-database-schema-using-hibernate is aplicable

Answer (score 0):

For automated database upgrades,  look at another tool specifically designed for the job. I would suggest [Liqiubase](http://liquibase.org).

Comment: Usually admin is executing SQL command manually. Making him to learn something new just to do things in other way is dead idea.
The way should be automation.